# How to get the full path of an executable in Java, if launched from Windows environment variable PATH?

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I want to get the path of an executable launched in Java, if the executable is kept in a location which is part of Windows environment variable `PATH`.

Say for example, we launch `NOTEPAD` in windows using the below code snippet. Here `notepad.exe` is kept under `Windows` folder which is a part of the Windows environment variable `PATH`. So no need to give the complete path of the executable here.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();         
Process process = runtime.exec("notepad.exe");
```

So my question is, how to get the absolute location of the executables/files in Java programs (in this case if `notepad.exe` is kept under `c:\windows`, inside java program I need to get path `c:\windows`), if they are launched like this from `PATH` locations?

Comment: There is no builtin way to do this. You need to manually pick apart the `PATH` elements and search for `notepad.exe` in each.

Comment: `system.env("PATH")` maybe (no idea myself).

Comment: This is brittle.  It'll depend on the configuration of the machines on which you run it.

Comment: @duffymo It is brittle, but there is no alternative (unless you shell out to `where`, as noted in Amila's answer). Even the [`which`](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/which/which.c?rev=HEAD&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) command-line utility (Unix version of `where`) is implemented that way (i.e., there's no library function for doing `execvp`-style lookups).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do this. But you can find it the same way the shell finds executables on `PATH`.

Split the value of the `PATH` variable, iterate over the entries, which should be directories, and the first one that contains `notepad.exe` is the executable that was used.

```
public static String findExecutableOnPath(String name) {
    for (String dirname : System.getEnv("PATH").split(File.pathSeparator)) {
        File file = new File(dirname, name);
        if (file.isFile() && file.canExecute()) {
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
    throw new AssertionError("should have found the executable");
}
```

Comment: Note that when searching on windows, you may also need to search for `File file = new File(dirname, name + ".exe");`. If you want your application to run on all the standard OSs, you may need to check for both flavors of file.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the location of an executable in Windows by:

```
where <executable_name>
```

For example:

`where mspaint` returns:

> C:\Windows\System32\mspaint.exe

And the following code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("where notepad.exe");
try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {
    File exePath = new File(in.readLine());
    System.out.println(exePath.getParent());
}
```

Will output:

> C:\Windows\System32

Comment: Note that the directory containing the executable must be in the PATH environment variable in order for "where" to find it.

Comment: @Ehcnalb, `where` works on Windows and on Mac OS X. On Linux you may use `which`.